# If $f$ is an automorphism of $Z$, and $I$ is the identity function on $Z$, show that f is either $I$ or $-I$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $f$ is an automorphism of $Z$, and $I$ is the identity function on $Z$, show that f is
either $I$ or $-I$

---

**Def** of *Automorphism* is that it maps to itself $f:Z \to Z$

**def** of *function*

1. $f:X \to Y$ $\forall x\in X, \exists y \: f(x)=y$
2. well defined

---

$1_i:Z \to Z$ maps to $Z$ where $1_i(z)=z*1$ again for evry $Z$ and is well defined. It is true for $-1_i: Z \to Z$ where $-1_i(z)=z*(-1)$

Is it proved by contradiction???

If the mapping is not $I $ or $-I$ then there is a contradiction??

Comment: automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ as ... a group? a ring?

Comment: It can't be ring automorphisms if $-I$ is an automorphism. @RobArthan

Comment: But you simply assumed ring automorphism, when that is the real question - what kind of automorphism. The OP hasn't told us.

Comment: suppose to be in groups

Comment: @RobArthan True, but my assumption makes the question a sensible homework question. There is a human logic to such questions, so the when an asker here muffs the question (and there is quite a bit of the question muffed) you can still sometimes determine the original intent. Here, I'd give you 95 to 5 that the original intent was a question about groups, not rings. But also, I never addressed the OP. I addressed you. The OP is confused. When you decide, based on really no evidence.

Comment: Nope: "used to convey that what is asserted is very likely though not known for certain." My point with the $-I$ comment was, no, it is not very likely. @RobArthan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean *group* automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. bijections $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ which are also group homomorphisms.

The easiest way to prove this is first to look at the family of group *endo*morphisms on $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. I claim that if $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism, then $f(x) = f(1) \cdot x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. The idea here is that if I know $f(1)$, then I know, say, 
\begin{align*}
f(5) & = f(1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1) \\
& = f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) \\
& = 5 \cdot f(1) .
\end{align*}
Basically, I can "build" $\mathbb{Z}$ from $1$; consequently, I can build any homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z}$ from $1$ as well.

From here, once we know that the group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself are all just equivalent to multiplying by some integer, call it $C$, we can ask when a morphism is bijective. Here, we need only observe that if $f(x) = C x$, then $f(x) = y$ if and only if $y / C = x$. But this means that $1$ is only in the image of $f$ if $1/C \in \mathbb{Z}$, which occurs only if $C = \pm 1$. Thus if $x \mapsto Cx$ is onto, then $C = \pm 1$.

As others have said, in the future, pay attention to what kind of homomorphism you're dealing with. Context will often make it clear, but a little clarity never hurts, especially when you first get into a topic.

Comment: Yes, the group automorphisms admit $f(n) = \pm n$, unlike the ring homomorphisms!

Comment: I guess you can also say that if $f(1) \ne \pm 1$, then $f$ can't be surjective, although one might need the division algorithm to prove this formally,

Comment: Well that's what I showed.

Answer (score 2):

The kicker, here, is that anything that says "morphism" should probably have a context. So far, you haven't provided any, so it could easily be a *set* automorphism--*i.e.*: a bijective function--such as $f(n)=n+1$.

However, suppose we require more. For example, suppose we require that $f$ be a *group* automorphism--*i.e.*: a bijective function satisfying the following:

- $\forall x,y\in\Bbb Z,$ $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),$
- $f$ is a bijection $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z.$

Then one *can* show the desired results.

Comment: No one can't, because then we have that $x \mapsto - x$ isn't a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @AJY: /sigh/ My thanks! It will be fixed promptly. :-)

Comment: @CameronBuie: there is nothing to fix. AJY's snotty comment doesn't invalidate your answer. The fact that $x \mapsto -x$ is not a ring homomorphism on the integers does not invalidate the statement that any ring homomorphism on the integers is either $x \mapsto x$ or $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: I'm with Rob Arthan on this one!

Comment: @RobArthan You're right, I did misread the problem. That being said, I think that in this context, we can infer that the OP means group automorphisms (suggested by the fact they didn't know to qualify the category the morphisms were in).

Answer (score 1):

I take it that by "automorphism" our OP Iloveass2 means "ring automorphism", in which case we have:

***The only non-trivial ring homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ is the identity map $I$.***

For let $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ be any ring homomorphism.  Then

$f(1) = f(1^2) = f(1)f(1), \tag 1$

which may only be satisfied if

$f(1) = 0 \tag 2$

or

$f(1) = 1; \tag 3$

in the former case for any $n \in \Bbb Z$ we have

$f(n) = f(n \cdot 1) = f(n) \cdot f(1) = f(n) \cdot 0 = 0, \tag 4$

so $f$ is in fact trivial contrary to our hypothesis, and thus we rule out case (2); if $f(1) = 1$, then

$f(2) = f(1 + 1) = f(1) + f(1) = 1 + 1 = 2, \tag 5$

$f(3) = f(2 + 1) = f(2) + f(1) = 2 + 1 = 3; \tag 6$

if $0 < k \in \Bbb Z$ and

$f(k) = k, \tag 7$

then

$f(k + 1) = f(k) + f(1) = k + 1; \tag 7$

thus we see that

$f(n) = n \tag 8$

for all $n \in \Bbb N$.  Also,

$f(0) = f(0 + 0) = f(0) + f(0), \tag 9$

whence

$f(0) = 0, \tag{10}$

and since for $n \ge 0$

$n + (-n) = 0, \tag{11}$

$f(n) + f(-n) = f(n + (-n)) = f(0) = 0, \tag{12}$

so

$f(-n) = -f(n) = -n, \tag{13}$

and we see $f$ fixes the negative integers as well as the non-zero ones. It follows that

$\forall n \in \Bbb Z \; f(n) = n, \tag{14}$

so we conclude

$f = I, \tag{15}$

the identity map on $\Bbb Z$.

I think it is worth noting that the *only* place we invoke multiplication in the above is to show $f(1) = 1$.  Once we have that, the rest is all about addition.  One might even say,

***"God made One; all else, the work of man!"***